# How to prevent undefined behavior, from a user/new developer perspective?

Tags: c, memory-management, heap-memory

So the question is, how does the original developer prevent a situation where user/new developer is trying to access a *free*'d memory element.

```
int *num=(int *)malloc(n*sizeof(int));
int i;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
 scanf("%d",&num[i]);        
}    

for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
temp = some_function(x);        
} 

free(num);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
  printf("\nnum[%d]= %d\n",i,num[i]);        
}
```

P.S.: The above code works and actually prints out data in array. Which is not our intention. 
[EDIT] Sorry if I was not clear enough. Someone suggested to ask this as a separate question, I thought why not. Here's the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851778/free-wont-delete-memory-allocated-to-the-pointer-int-array-using-free-twice)

Comment: _The above code works and actually prints out data in array._.. welcome to UB.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: The code works on one particular platform, probably in a debug build.  Running this one a different system (or a release build) may crash.  it depends on the memory allocator.  Some allocators will zero (or set all bytes to something else) after free, so you would get different results then.

Comment: _Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question._

Comment: Thumb injury is prevented by not hitting your thumb with a hammer. Undefined behavior is prevented by not writing bad code.

Comment: @SebastianRedl thanks for your input, I totally agree with you, its not the developers responsibility to care about user/new developers unethical style of coding. Im just trying to find out ways to be safe :)

Comment: One of the easiest fixes in the snippet above is to Always (*always*) validate the return of `scanf` to know whether or not your program is processing garbage from that point on.

Comment: @SouravGhosh sorry for the confusion, original post was here. 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851778/free-wont-delete-memory-allocated-to-the-pointer-int-array-using-free-twice]

Answer (score 4):

The fact that your code "works" is a manifestation of the *undefined behaviour* that you're experiencing when reading memory that you no longer own.

You *could* consider setting `num` to `NULL` after the first `free` call. Then writing `num[i]` will almost certainly crash the program. It can also occasionally be useful: a `free` called with `NULL` passed as the pointer is a no-op.

There's little else you can do unfortunately.

But, in general, setting `free`d pointers to `NULL` leads to sloppy programming so I tend to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you can do is set num=NULL.

More generally you can add a malloc hook to write garbage to the memory before freeing the memory (probably debug only). This will force a crash if the memory contains pointers or print garbage in this case when accessing freed memory.

Also since you are talking C++, make use of smart pointers.

Edit: fixed up the crash issue.

Comment: How will garbage values crash the program anymore than values already there?

Comment: @4386427 It might not crash the program, but it will prevent access to the original data thus making a bug easier to spot.

Comment: Sorry was thinking about the more general case when the memory contained pointers.